# Remove the empty space present below the image

Tags: html, css

we can see lot of empty space in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/) as below the image. I want to hide those empty space.

[image]

```
.main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

body, button, input, select, table, textarea {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #636363;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="custom_case">
    <div class="custom_case_left">
        <h1 class="cc1">Custom Cases</h1>
        <h2 class="cc2">Make Your Own design</h2>
    </div>

<?php


$brandSelect = '<select id="brand_select">';
$brandSelect .= '<option value="">My Brand</option>';

$brandSelect .= '</select>';


echo '<select id="model_select"><option value="">My Model</option></select>';
?>


<div class ="cc3">
<div class ="cc4">
<a href= "><span class ="cc5"> See Cases > </span> </a>
</div>

</div>
```

I dont want to give so much empty space between image and below footer

please help me for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out for you!

Your image of the phone cases is what is causing the space issue.

```
.custom_case_right img {
   /*float:right;*/
   /*bottom:320px;*/
}
```

That will fix the spacing beneath your image. Now your image is displaying improperly and to fix do this

```
.custom_case_right {
    float:right;
    margin-top:-310px;
}
```

These two changes ought to take care of it for you. I tested this out in Chrome.

You'll still need to think about how you want to have your image behave as your viewport shrinks though.

Answer (score 1):

trying to make `img`:

- `line-height: 0;`
- `vertical-align`: top or bottom;

Comment: i used this code

`.custom_case_right img {

line-height: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;

}` but didt worked for me.

Comment: which browser you using? I didn't see space below the image in Chrome

Comment: in chrome , please scroll down little bit after you see image

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix the height of main-container.

```
enter code here.main-container{
```

height:550px;
}

Comment: .main-container{ height:550px;}

Comment: you can check here, i usd inspect element and gave `height:550px;`

Comment: can you please tell me which `main-container` you are tellling, can you give me line number and file name

Answer (score 1):

Make this changes to your `classes`:

```
.col1-layout .col-main {
 position: relative;     
 }

.custom_case_right {
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

And in your image remove position `absolute`, add this style instead:

```
   .custom_case_right img {
    position: relative;
    width: 620px;
    height: 100%;
  }
```